# Multiple ng-controller directives using "controller as x" on the same element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

1. Why isn't it possible in Angular to put two `ng-controller` directives on the same element and
2. Which are the possible mitigation scenarios for this *problem* - like custom directives or HTML element nesting with single `ng-controller` directives to name a couple, but there may be others as well

Something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerOne as c1" ng-controller="ControllerTwo as c2">
    {{ c1.value }}, {{ c2.value }}
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/t6xohz87/) that sets two controllers on the same element.

Comment: For one thing, it's not legal to have more than one attribute with the same name in HTML. This also smells of a bad idea. Is putting one inside the other not an option?

Comment: @JLRishe: I haven't even thought about HTML spec. That's a very good argument! It's interesting (from my fiddle example) that only the first controller gets instantiated. I would expect the second one, but these kind of things could be tested with pure HTML which one takes precedence when multiple attributes are present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can't be possible since `ng-controller` creates isolated scope for the current element. So this is not possible. So there can't be two isolated scope on a same element.

You need to change your code to:

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerOne as c1">
    <div ng-controller="ControllerTwo as c2">
        {{ c1.value }}, {{ c2.value }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Also its not valid to have same name attribute in any html tag.

Comment: Well... If you created two directives and put them both on the same element, you would have **access to both** controllers even though on the same element...

Comment: Yes, its again only possible if directive are not marked with `scope: true` i.e. the directives are not isolated.

Comment: ng-controller does not create an isolated scope - it creates a child scope. It is possible to have multiple child scopes on the same element through directive's that implement child scopes, but an element can have at most one ngController, and at most one ng-controller scope - by design.

Comment: Oh, but the angular code uses `scope: true` for `ng-controller` directive that means it creates an isolated scope.