# Angularjs <div ng-controller override second ng-controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, d3.js

I'm using AngularJS for my charts.

I have to create two charts, they both use the same nav-bar.

I am able to display both charts on the screen, however; only `<div ng-controller="first ">` work with nav-bar. My second  `<div ng-controller="second">` get overridden.

```
<div ng-controller="first">
    <div ng-controller="second ">
```

This is how I have it on my HTML,

If I replace  `<div ng-controller="second ">` with `<div ng-controller="first">`, ng-controller="second" will work just fine with dropdownm but "first" will be overridden

Here is my [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/qezepi/edit?html,js,output)

I have also tried this [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27781172/multiple-ng-controller-directives-using-controller-as-x-on-the-same-element) either it didn't work for me or I couldn't get it to work.

My goal is to update both charts after making selection from dropdown menu. Right only one works because of the `<div>` issue

Comment: your question isn't clear at all.  what are you trying to say here? " have replace I write `<div ng-controller="second ">` this will work."?  That code is identical to the code right above it?

Comment: it's still very difficult to understand what you are asking, but I *think* you might be asking how to have a child element access an element from it's parent.  (in this case, `second` is a child of `first`).  try looking into `$parent`.

Comment: @Claies I try to edit my question to be little bit more clear. What basically happening is, which ever `<div>` come first, that `<div>` work with dropdown selection. Other `<div>` gets overriden

Answer (score 1):

So you want to have same filters for two charts, created from the data available in two different controllers.

Your current approach will just update the values attached with ng-model for the second controller. Instead, try using a service. Lets call it `chart.service`

Now this service can have the values for filters like date, month year etc. Let both the controllers use this service and on update from UI, update the values in the service using your controllers. Since service will have a single instance, both controllers will now have the same value of filters and both your charts will be correctly shown.

Comment: Vivek, thats sounds like exactly what I need, if its not too much work, can you show me a demo? or use my jsbin? I really appreciate for helps

Comment: Just try it out with a service and let me know if you have any issues. You know about the whole "teach a man how to fish thingy" :)

Comment: I'll try, also share here what I did :)

Comment: I'm still trying to create custom service, I never created one before, so its taking a lot learning curve especially I am very new with Angularjs. whenever I am done I will still share with you for feedback or errors :)

Comment: I kind of give up :/ I did learn how to create custom service then inject into my controller to use. But I have I do not know to do this part " have the values for filters like date, month year etc"

Comment: Just declare scope variables in service that will hold the values. You can then create functions to update these values and retrieve these values.

Comment: If you want a more crude way, you can look at VALUES in angular js which can hold values and can be edited as well. Here is a good overview on that https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/01/14/angularjspart-9-values-and-constants/